# Openstreetmap Nominatim web service API - Result language

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

I notices something strange:

When I execute simple request:

```
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=45&lon=10&zoom=18&addressdetails=0
```

From the PC web browser for location located in my country (not 45/10) I get the result in English, although we have different language here.

But when I execute the very same request, without any other data like headers from application running on a mobile device - I do get the result in our local language.

Why this is happen? I familiar with the `accept-language` param of Nominatim, but as seen - I'm not specify him nor touching headers in my request.

Answer (score 4):

Your browser and other HTTP/HTTPS clients will sent an [`Accept-Language`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4) field in the HTTP request header. This can for example look like:

```
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3\r\n
```

Which means: prefer German (*de-DE* or *de*) with an quality value of *0.8*, then US-English (*en-US*) with an quality value of *0.5* (i.e. lower than German), then English (*en*) with an quality value of *0.3*) (i.e. lower than German and US-English). Most browser will always sent this field in their requests, the preferred languages can be configured via your browser settings.

The [`accept-language`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Parameters) parameter for Nominatim overrides the `Accept-Language` field of the HTTP request allowing you to request results in a language different to your browser settings.